# Insert data in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables and I want to insert data into that three tables as per their respective data.

Query:

```
with acupressure_point_data as (
    insert into acupressure_point(id, url)
        values('LL909', 'ww/33/11')
    returning id as acupressure_point_id
),
acupressure_sub_type as (
    insert into acupressure_point_region_sub_type
        (acupressure_point_id, region_sub_type_id)
        values(acupressure_point_id , '9898')
    returning id as acupressure_sub_type_id
);
```

But it gives the error as:

> "ERROR: syntax error at end of input Position"

I can not understood this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to return from the SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

For PostgerSQL:

```
with acupressure_point_data as ( -- insert into first table with output
                                 insert into acupressure_point(id, url)
                                 values('LL909', 'ww/33/11')
                                 returning id as acupressure_point_id )
-- insert into second table, use CTE output
insert into acupressure_point_region_sub_type(acupressure_point_id, region_sub_type_id)
SELECT acupressure_point_id , '9898'
FROM acupressure_point_data
-- return id for both tables 
returning acupressure_point_id, id as acupressure_sub_type_id;
```

MySQL does not allow INSERT in CTE. Use separate queries and LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: Yes '9898' is not from acupressure_point_data. And this is not literal, i stored it as variable in the python script and that variable i send in the query as '9898'.

Comment: @Suhel Well, send it into your query as 3rd parameter (1st and 2nd are 'LL909' and 'ww/33/11' respectively).